Did Artem and Anna Dultsev's children really have no idea that their parents were connected to Russia?
Kremlin spokesperson Dmitry Peskov has claimed that the children of Artem and Anna Dultsev (two of the Russian spies who were part of the August 1, 2024 prisoner exchange) did not know they were Russian until they were on the plane to Moscow. From this NBC article:

Their children attended an international school in Ljubljana and, according to Kremlin spokesman Dmitry Peskov, were only told on the plane to Moscow that they were Russian.
"Before that, they did not know that they were Russian, that they had anything to do with our country," Peskov said in a statement on Friday.

But the Slovenian police had publicly arrested the Dultsev parents all the way back in 2022 on the grounds of suspicion of spying for Russia, and the children were then placed into foster care.
Did the children not have any idea why their parents had been arrested - or even that they had been arrested at all - even though this information was easily publicly available? It seems implausible that they would not have come across any of the publicly available information about their parents' connection to Russia.

It's a fair question, but I fear it might not be answerable if Slovenia has anything like privacy laws that prevent those who work with such children from speaking to the press on such matters.

The link you posted appears to be pretty definitive.  Other news outlets are reporting the same but that's not obviously more definitive than the Politico article.  It seems pretty reasonable to me that an 11- and 8-year old who were 9 and 6 when their parents were arrested wouldn't have done an extensive search of publicly available information about the arrest and would likely believe whatever they were told.  And it seems pretty reasonable that their parents wouldn't have admitted they were Russian spies while they were in custody.

@JustinCave: they are reporting what the Russian media is saying, which may or may not be the whole truth.

Everyone is reporting what the Russian media is saying, true.  But it seems unlikely that there is anything more definitive out there.

Apparently the kids are aged 8 and 11.  When you were that age, would you have noticed your parents were spies?  Would you have told your 8-year-old and 11-year-old kids you were a spy?

@Kyralessa: the Q seems to be if the foster parents/care did that. Their natural parents already said on Russian TV, which is what Politico is reporting, that they [the natural parents] hadn't.

I was going to add the full quote from the article, but after reading it I'm confused about what your question is. The part of the quote where you have "..." just says "they did not know that they were Russian", so the spokesperson was saying the kids did not know they were Russian or had any connections to Russia. Nobody is saying they didn't know what their parents were arrested for or that they didn't hear about the claims, they're just saying that they didn't know it was all true until they were actually heading to Russia.

I’m voting to close this question because it asks about personal motivations or mind-states which is considered off-topic here, because there is no way to use empirical evidence to answer the question of what these children thought or believed.

@Giter I guess it depends on how you define "having anything to do with Russia". I would say that having your parents arrested on charges (even false charges) of spying for Russia would count as "having something to do with Russia". But I could see someone else requiring a closer connection than that.
